# How to update the SpriteKit node for an ARAnchor?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, augmented-reality, arkit

I have a SpriteKit based ARKit application that shows SKSpriteNodes at various anchor points in the AR space. I am providing the node for each anchor using the `ARSKViewDelegate` method

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode?
```

That works when I first add the anchor, but at point in the runtime I would like to switch the nodes for some anchors to different nodes. How do I force the `ARSKView` to "refresh" and call that node for anchor method again?

Answer (score 0):

Use [view(_:didUpdate:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arskviewdelegate/2865590-view) instance method.

> This method tells the delegate that a SpriteKit node's properties have been updated to match the current state of its corresponding anchor.

```
optional func view(_ view: ARSKView, 
           didUpdate node: SKNode, 
               for anchor: ARAnchor)
```

And don't forget about delegate allowing you to use a mentioned method:

```
weak var delegate: ARSKViewDelegate? { get set }
```